# Do Seychelles' Immigration officers object to unofficial accommodation places?

Tags: proof-of-accommodation, seychelles

Do they object to unofficial accommodation places like Airbnb, as opposed to licensed hotels and resorts?

I had a friend who had first a booking with a resort for a few days, and an Airbnb booking for places after that. He told me the immigration officer only checked for the first accommodation and not all, so try making the first accomodation place a non-Airbnb place.

I am told they are pretty relaxed with couples who are on their honeymoon. I want to mix it up - luxury with budget options for the entire course of the trip.

Comment: Did they actually check or did they just want to record the physical address?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Just took a quick look in my friend's case. But did ask for passport size photographs for the couple in front of them, not sure why.

Comment: When I went to the Seychelles, I stayed at my Uncle's holiday house on Eden Island. They were pretty good with a letter from him confirming the address so Airbnb should be fine. I think they just want you to have confirmed accommodation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they only check the first accommodation and even I was told informally there is an exception for people that go to Praslin. In my case, earlier this year I was going to La Digue so I did not test that but they only checked that I had accommodations there and all that was needed was a printout confirming that I had a booking. Mine was for a B&B and not a hotel or resort and neither were any of my stays on other islands.

Comment: Cool! Can you elaborate on the exception you mentioned?

Comment: As I said, I was only told informally that if you connected to Praslin, then advanced booking is one required. Since this is not a rule though, it may depend on the immigration agent you get if he applies it or not.